# Git check compare is slow

Tags: git, github, zip

I am currently working on a project that has a directory with a lot of small files within it that don't change.  I know that I can add it to the git ignore but I still want them in my repo.  Will zipping the directory shorten the time it takes to pull/merge and if so are there any other ways to shorten the process?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend zipping a directory like this; Git is already quite efficient. What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Will zipping the directory shorten the time it takes to pull/merge and if so are there any other ways to shorten the process?  In other words, I want to shorten the process it takes for git to compare the 100,000 files I have in a directory.

Comment: why is zipping a bad idea?

Comment: I'd flip the question around and ask you why you think it's a *good* idea. I don't think it buys you anything, and it adds complexity to your source tree. It also makes merging difficult if you ever do need to change one of those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is fast enough.

If you want them in your repository - you will have to add, commit and push them once. If they don't change, they will never again be transferred and will NOT influence the pull and, moreover, merge time.

It is because git stores snapshots of files and not their diffs.

[image]

Say, you've got a file. It has sha1 of `abcdef123456`. Imagine a conversation between local and remote repos:

**First push:**
Local: "I've got abcdef123456 here!"
Remote: "Please transfer it to me"

**Next pushes**
Local: "I've got abcdef123456 here!"
Remote: "Heh, that's boring. I've got it already."

Comment: When I use the pull it takes a long time b/c of those files.  it tries to compare each one to the origin files.

Comment: @SariRahal well, it should only compare sha1 codes. They are not recalculated and files are not diff-ed on pull.